# Return true/false to javascript from php file

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using $.post method to make ajax calls.
I have a script (php) that checks for user existing in database and returns (echo's) 1 if exist and 0 if not. 
Is it possible to return true and false so javascript recognize it as boolean ?

Comment: Why do you need it? it is quite easy to check strings in js

Comment: One reason for wanting to deal with Boolean `true`/`false` in JavaScript as well as PHP can be to maintain conceptual unity. I won't have to think that it's PHP so use `true`, or it's JavaScript so use `1` and also no conversion required when to and fro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

mentions an option to parse data as JSON, so in theory you could use php to echo data in json form.

Answer (score 3):

No, the values will always be returned as text. You need to compare the values in your JavaScript.

```
if (data == '1') {
   //it's true
} else {
   // it's false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the string `"0"` is interpreted as `false` by JavaScript and `"1"` is interpreted as `true`, so you can simply work with the string value as a boolean. But then you can't use `===` to compare.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, js takes 0 like a false.

So you can use

if(ans) ...;
else ...

I'm not sure, but try it!