# Return true to jquery from php file

Tags: php, jquery

I was looking at this question: [Return true/false to javascript from php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626509/return-true-false-to-javascript-from-php-file)

But is not what I'm looking for, as I don't need to return text/strings in `JSON`.

What I want is to return true or false statements from loaded php file to `jQuery`.

`jQuery`: (How I think it could work)

```
if($("#lvlupann").load("/templ/checknlvl.php") == true){
                        $("#lvlupann").addClass("nlvlann"); 
                    }
```

And the mighty `php` file : **(checknlvl.php)**

```
if(1 == 1){
        return true;    
    }
```

But obviously it doesn't return true/false, and class is not added... I know I'm going probably wrong on it, but don't know what to overwrite...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: if($("#lvlupann").load("/templ/checknlvl.php") == "true"){
                        $("#lvlupann").addClass("nlvlann"); 
                    }

Comment: It would be best to just make a helper function and turn the response into either true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

The `.load()` method is asynchronous and does not return the value from the server (it returns the element that it was called on: `$("#lvlupann")`), so using the returned value in an `if` statement does not make sense.

You have to wait for the request to finish before you can use the value, like so:

```
$("#lvlupann").load("/templ/checknlvl.php", function (value) {
    if (value == true) {
        $("#lvlupann").addClass("nlvlann");
    }
});
```

As for the PHP file, the `return true;` will just stop the script. It does not send anything to the client. In order to send two or more things from PHP to the client you need to package the output in some fashion.

The `$.get` method would be useful:

```
$.get('/templ/checknlvl.php').done(function (data) {
    $("#lvlupann").html(data.content);
    if (data.success) {
        $("#lvlupann").addClass("nlvlann");
    }
});

<?php
echo json_encode([
    'content' => '<strong>Some content...</strong>',
    'success' => true,
]);
die;
```

If all you want to do is get a boolean value from the PHP script then something like this would do it:

```
$.get('/templ/checknlvl.php').done(function (value) {
    if (value === "true") {
        $("#lvlupann").addClass("nlvlann");
    }
});

<?php
if (1 == 1) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
die;
```